# C printing char array as float

Tags: c, floating-point, unions

I'm trying to print a char array of 4 elements as a float number. The compiler(gcc) won't allow me to write `z.s={'3','4','j','k'};` in the main() function, why?

```
#include <stdio.h>

union n{
    char s[4];
    float x;
};
typedef union n N;

int main(void)
{
    N z;
    z.s[0]='3';
    z.s[1]='4';
    z.s[2]='j';
    z.s[3]='k';
    printf("f=%f\n",z.x);
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the program above is: `f=283135145630880207619489792.000000` , a number that is much larger than a float variable can store; the output should be, in scientific notation, `4.1977085E-8`.
So what's wrong?

Comment: [Endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), perhaps?

Comment: Have you considered big/little Indian problems?

Comment: I guess any x86 or x86-64 PC would give the same result.

Comment: if i were you, i would write this array into a file using fwrite then read as a float using fread (reading a float). This can give you a hint about endianness problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`z.s={'3','4','j','k'};` would assign one array to another. C doesn't permit that, though you could declare the second and `memcpy` to the first.

The largest finite value that a single-precision IEEE float can store is 3.4028234 × 10^38, so 283135145630880207619489792.000000, which is approximately 2.8313514 × 10^26 is most definitely in range.

Assuming your chars are otherwise correct, the knee-jerk guess would be that you've got your endianness wrong.

EDIT:
34jk if taken from left to right, as on a big-endian machine is:

```
0x33 0x34 0x6a 0x6b
= 0011 0011, 0011 0100, 0110 1010, 0110 1011
```

So:

```
sign = 0
exponent = 011 0011 0 = 102 (dec), or -25 allowing for offset encoding
mantissa = [1] 011 0100 0110 1010 0110 1011 = 11823723 / (2^23)
```

So the value would be about 4.2 × 10^-8, which is what you want.

In little endian:

```
0x6b 0x6a 0x34 0x33 
= 0110 1011, 0110 1010, 0011 0100, 0011 0011

sign = 0
exponent = 110 1011 0 = 214 (dec) => 87
mantissa = [1]110 1010 0011 0100 0011 0011 = 15348787 / (2^23)
```

So the value would be about 2.8 * 10^26, which is what your program is outputting. It's a safe conclusion you're on a little endian machine.

Summary then: byte order is different between machines. You want to use your bytes the other way around — try `kj43`.

Comment: So a different compiler could give a different result?

Comment: What about precision? I thought the float mantissa can store only 7 digits.

Comment: Different CPUs would definitely give different results. When reading a 32-bit value, some consider the most significant byte to be the first but some consider it to be the last. I think you've just used English reading order (ie, left to right) on a little endian CPU (ie, one that reads right to left).

Comment: Yes, it is, it's a Linux x86-64, Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

What you actually see is {'k' 'j' '4' '3'}